# How can I add custom less file and in a particular theme compile less file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, less-css, less-import

How can I add custom less file and in a particular theme compile less file in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add new file here

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\source\_new.less
```

and import this file in source file given path below

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\source\_sources.less
```

import your file

(if there is not available _source.less file in your theme then go to `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source` folder and copy file in your custom theme)

```
@import '_new.less';
```

1. clear cache
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Tried this and it is not working

Comment: @Scott try this: app/design/frontend/Vendor/Tname/web/css/source/_extend.less

Comment: thanks Yusuf. that's eventually what I figured out

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is not working I don't know how its accepted:
If you want to add custom common css file, you have to follow below steps:

1) create file at following locationi in your custom theme

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\source\_common.less
```

2) create _extend.less file at following location

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\source\_extend.less
```

3) add following line at top of this file

```
@import '_common.less';
```

just clear cache & generate content if on production.

Comment: where should i put ' @import '_common.less';  at? thanksw

Comment: in side _extend.less file. Which is actually file in your theme who is extending the magento's module css file. In which you want to add modifications.
See topic how can I extend magento css file?