# Unable to import custom less file in custom theme's modules in Magento2

Tags: magento2, static-content, custom-theme, less-compilation, less-import

I have created a custom theme in Magento 2 and I want to add `_customvariables.less` and `_custommixins.less` in all other less files.

I have added these files in the following location.

```
magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_customvariables.less
magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_custommixins.less
```

I have created separate less files for different areas like `customer-account`,`cms-pages`,`category-pages`,`product-pages` now when I tried to import `_customvariables.less` and `_custommixins.less` via following code

```
@import '../../../Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_variables.less';
@import '../../../Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_mixins.less';
```

I have got following errors in `system.log`

```
[2018-06-29 12:55:43] main.CRITICAL: File path 'magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/Magento_Cms/web/../../Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_variables.less' is forbidden for security reasons. [] []
```

When i try to run `php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` then i found follwoing errors in cli

```
Compilation from source: magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/web/css/media.less . File path 'magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/web/../Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_custommixins.less' is forbidden for security reasons.
```

I am using `Koala` for less compilation it successfully compiles with the `@import` but when we clean the `pub/static` directory or `deploy static content` the CSS files are not created properly.

I have read this thread ([How can I custom less file and compile less file in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142783/how-can-i-custom-less-file-and-compile-less-file-in-magento-2)), but in my case the `_custommixins.less` and the files which imports are in different directories like

```
File which imports : magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/Magento_Customer/web/css/source/customer_acc.less
File which need to import : magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_custommixins.less
```

Currently, I'm not using `grunt`/`gulp`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create folder named **module** in `magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/` folder and add `_customvariables.less` and `_custommixins.less` files in this folder.

Then import these two files in `magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme1/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less` file like below:

```
@import 'module/_customvariables.less';
@import 'module/_custommixins.less';
```

Run command `php bin/magento s:up` and `php bin/magento s:s:d -f`